# LDAP - Get CN, DC, OU for logged in account Windows

Tags: windows, ldap, authentication

I am not very familiar with LDAP but need to add LDAP authentication to an existing application. I am trying to test LDAP authentication using `ldapsearch` but it keeps failing I suspect it due to me using incorrect CN, DC and OUs

I am currently logged into my domain account on windows. Can I obtain the required parameters from this logged in user and use it as the bindDN ?

Comment: You should contact the administrator of the LDAP server to ask them what credentials you need.

Comment: For AD you can use simple bind with the username@domain/password (or Kerberos), you don’t need a initial DN for that. After that you would do a subtree search with userPrincipalName and objectClass=user (if you need the DN)

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what Windows OS you are running, but both Windows 7 as Windows 10 have the 'Remote Server Administration Tools' (you might need to install them first, which might be a problem if you do not have administrative access to install software on your computer). A part of it are the so called 'dstools'.

If you have it installed, then you can run something like this:

```
dsquery user -samid <your_user_name>
```

which will return the distinguishdname of your user account.

Having written all this, if you need to add ldap support to a business application, then you can easily get this kind of information from your IT organization support, they will provide you with all the info you need.